# Почему не работают static файлы django после выключения debug=false в nginx+gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx

ubuntu+nginx+gunicorn не работают static файлы после установки debug=False. В чем может быть проблема?

**nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gm.hubcrm.ru;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/lapitsky/crm3/CRM3/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/lapitsky/crm3/CRM3/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ServiceCRM3/static'),]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '...',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '...',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

При отключенной дебаге статика не сервится динамически. Смотри urls.py.

Собери статическую статику командой

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

И подкинь эту папку нгинксу напрямую